# Add column in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, csv, excel, concatenation

Is it possible to add a column in the attribute table in QGIS that is a concatenation of two other columns? For example I have a column "Genus" and a column "Species" and I would like to create a column "GenusSpecies" that looks something like

GenusSpecies

Martes foina

Vulpes vulpes

Vulpes lagopus

etc.

I cannot edit my csv in excel to do it because it is 2GB in size and crashes my computer and says there isn't enough memory.

If there is a way to make and add the column with the Mac terminal/command line that would also work too

Comment: I think you need to have an edit-able format (geopackage, shapefile) to do the concatenation in an edit session.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Add your file to QGIS.  Open the attribute table by right clicking the file in the layers menu.  Click the *Open Field Calculator* button.  You will be presented with a dialog box like below.  Ensure you have selected *Create a new field*, name the field with a name less than 10 characters long.  Select *Output field type* as Text.  Finally set the *field width* to some value at least as large as your longest name.  In blue I have selected an expression from two attributes in my data.  Your expression might be something like `"Genus" || ' ' || "Species"` (assuming your columns are actually named that.  Hit OK.  This will fill your new column with the genus and species from the other two cells and place a blank space between the two words.

[image]